# SQL - JOIN 2 tables with either NULL OR MAX

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables in Teradata that i need to LEFT JOIN.
The first one includes clients, the second their details with the validity end date. NULL represents currently valid.

Table1

| client_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Table2

| client_id | valid_end |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31.12.2021 |
| 1 | 31.12.2022 |
| 2 | 31.12.2020 |
| 2 | null |

I need to left join the two tables using the most recent record for each client from Table2.
In case there is a currently valid record with NULL, it is used. If there is not any NULL record, the highest date is used.

Result

| client_id | valid_end |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31.12.2022 |
| 2 | null |

Tried a lot using QUALIFY and MAX, but never reached the requested result. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt. (Probably not too hard to modify.)

Comment: I wouldn't consider using nulls to represent anything other than missing data a best practice.  For your "current" row, you could use some date in the distant future, like 9999-12-31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER instead of MAX, NULLS FIRST sorts NULL before the highest date:

```
qualify
   row_number() 
   over (partition by client_id
         order by valid_end desc NULLS FIRST) = 1
```

Comment: OMG, now it is obvious! Great, thank you.